# Image flickers because image does not load on IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, css

I have this annoying problem with my code.I am building a simple page and I have an image that must change while scrolling down the page. It works perfect in Chrome, but in EDGE and Firefox on the initial scroll the image flickers when changed for the first time.
After that it is all fine. I think it is because I load the images with display:none property , so I assume they are not "downloaded properly" before actually rendered on the page.
I was wondering how I can resolve this issue?

Here is the web address

http://www.kristiyan.website

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Though not idea, you can "pre-load" the images with `<img src="yourimage" style="position:relative; z-index:-1">`. This way it's already loaded when you're scrolling down.

Comment: I am already preloading them, but obviously while they are not displayed , it still flickers

Comment: Try preloading them with z-index:-1 then z-index:1 instead of display:none.

Comment: That`s actually a very good advice. I was doing it already but with z-index 0 and pics were stacking one under another and wasn`t looking that good , but the -1 will do the job.Thanks a lot man